# In python, if a file opened using the `w` access flag opened using ASCII-encoding, UTF-8, Unicode, or something else?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, io, output

In python, if a file opened using the `w` access flag will the data written to file be:

> - ASCII-encoded
> - encoded using the UTF-8 scheme
> - encoded using some other scheme?

If it is platform or system specific, how do we find out which encoding scheme is used, or is there a different library I should use for file I/O for which we explicitly specify the encoding scheme?

```python
file = open("data.txt", "w")
```

Comment: It does not depend on the file mode.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the `open` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> In text mode, if `encoding` is not specified the encoding used is platform-dependent: [`locale.getencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getencoding) is called to get the current locale encoding.

You can always specify it manually mind you; that's what the optional `encoding` argument is for.